# Change Insert Mode cursor on Veovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I think I'm getting old.  My resolution this year was to use VIM.  I'm trying hard to use neovim but for the life of me I can't seem to change the cursor in insert mode.  I just can't find the vertical line on the screen.  Ideally I would like it to be bright red and configured in my init.vim file rather than typed every time I start the editor.  I read the help and as many online links as I could find.  But I just turned 50.  Can you please just treat me like a dinosaur and give me whatever snippet I need to copy into my init.vim?

Comment: Unsure on changing the cursor, but there are two other options that can be used to help identify line and column the cursor is on: `set cursorcolumn` and `set cursorline`. Turning both on give a sort of crosshair as to the location of the cursor. Colours can be set using the `CursorLine` and `CursorColumn` highlighting groups.

Comment: Add your OS info, GUI/TUI etc. Try Vim instead of Neovim. Read `:h 'guicursor'` and `:h hl-Cursor`